# There is no LE in android.bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm trying to make a BLE connetion from Bluetooth.

So i tried to use

```
import android.bluetooth.le.BluetoothLeScanner;
```

But there is no le in my

```
android.bluetooth.
```

I added following Codes in xml.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le" android:required="true"/>
```

and my build's apk is

```
 minSdkVersion 18
 targetSdkVersion 26
```

like this.

But there is no le still

[image]

What should i do?

Comment: which class or package are you trying to import?

Comment: android.bluetooth.le.ScanCallback
android.bluetooth.le.ScanFilter
android.bluetooth.le.ScanResult
android.bluetooth.le.ScanSettings
i want to import these packages

Comment: Maybe you could change your minSdkVersion to 21? Becuase this Bluetooth LE class was added in 21 and is not available on earlier versions.

Comment: @Chris623 No, with minSdkVersion 18 and target 26 should work. 18 is the min SDK with Bluetooth LE.

Comment: I took a huge mistake.... I didn't change my compileSdkVersion x(   Thanks for answering